# Pinterest save hover button not working- can I load pinit.js and pinit_main.js both on the same page?

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I am troubleshooting a problem I'm having with the pinterest save hover button. The save button for pinterest should appear for a user when hovering over an image. I have pinit.js added loaded on my site, however the button only appears about 20% of page loads.

I am noticing in the network tabs that along with pinit.js pinit_main.js- could this be causing a conflict? What is the difference between the two scripts?

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit_main.js?0.598328212150744"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">(function (d) {var f = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0],p = d.createElement('SCRIPT');p.type = 'text/javascript';p.async = true;p.src = '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js';f.parentNode.insertBefore(p, f);})(document);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code. It is working for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-pin-hover="true" async src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```